# Prevent facebook callback from appending '#_=_' to the redirected URL of my website using react-router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

How to prevent facebook callback from appending '# _ = _ ' to the redirected URL of my website.

NOTE: I am using ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing is to just reset it. Put this as close to your script's starting point as possible:

```
if (location.hash == "#_=_") location.hash = "";
```